# How to CreateSwapChainForHwnd

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-12

In the following code, where device is an instance of `ComPtr<ID3D12Device>` that was successfully initialized with `D3D12CreateDevice`, I am getting an failing `HRESULT`.  I get the value 0x887a0001.  I would appreciate any ideas as to what I am doing wrong.

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = {};
swapChainDesc.Width = 0;
swapChainDesc.Height = 0;
swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDesc.Stereo = FALSE;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
swapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_STRAIGHT;
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapChain;
ThrowIfFailed(factory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(device.Get(), wnd.handle(),
                                              &swapChainDesc, nullptr,
                                              nullptr, &swapChain));
```

Comment: What is the type of your `factory`? Note that you need to use the (currently undocumented) `IDXGIFactory4` for D3D12 swap chains.

Comment: Yes, factory is `IDXGIFactory4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to CreateSwapChain functions is now supposed to be an ID3D12CommandQueue* rather than the graphics device.

Also, set your AlphaMode to DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_UNSPECIFIED.

Comment: I changed to passing my `ID3D12CommandQueue` and that didn't change anything.

Comment: Why does the Alpha mode fix this?